# Pandas Styler: modifying data removes style

Tags: python, pandas

I want to mark all cells with negative value in my dataframe. Then I want to turn these negative values into positive ones, but this data modification removes the style of the excel sheet completely.

Is there any way to modify pandas.Styler data without removing the style?

```
styled = df_csv.style.applymap(lambda x: 'background-color: %s' % 'lightSalmon' if x < 0 else '')
styled.data = styled.data.apply(lambda x: abs(x))
styled.to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

Comment: `Styler` is an API designed to function **after** the data has been prepared. It does not work well with simultaneously styling and changing the data. However, as the answer shows, formatting the underlying data is of course possible and a key feature of the post-processing capabilities of Styler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Styler.format`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html):

```
styled = (df_csv.style.applymap(lambda x: 'background-color: %s' % 'lightSalmon' if x < 0 else '')
                .format({'data': lambda x: abs(x)}))

styled.to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```